# google chrome cannot connect to tomcat project running on aws-ec2-linux instance

Tags: linux, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I have done these things:

1. changed the tomcat default port:8080 to 80 in /usr/local/apache-xxx/xx/server.xml, it is the install-path
2. ```
   /etc/rc.d/init.d/iptables stop
   ```
3. add inbound rules:

   ```
   HTTP(type) Tcp(protocol) 80(port) anywhere(source)
   ```
4. In the browser I typed http://ipaddress:80/

The result was  "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT". What did I do wrong?

Comment: What address is the tomcat instance binding to? What address are you connecting to? If you go to the ec2 aws web page and select the instance do either values match up to "public" or "private" ip/hostname values? Are you certain tomcat is started? Are you able to connect to the address from the server instance using wget or curl?

Comment: Tks very much!!   I have made it. AWS do not open port 80 to Chinese user.